# Restkit 0.20.rc requires but doesn't contain several 0.10 items

Tags: objective-c, restkit

These protocols of 0.10 (re:  http://restkit.org/api/0.10.3/) are referenced in Restkit 0.20.rc but are obsolete  and also not included (re: http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0-rc1/) :

RKRequestDelegate
RKRequestSerializable

and these obsolete classes are also referenced in the 0.20.rc code but not included:
RKRequest
RKResponse

all referenced in 0.20 rc's RKObjectLoader.h (Which is itself a 0.10.x class and seemingly obsolete in 0.20 rc so why is it in the fresh 0.20.0-rc1 download ?)

Maybe someone with more Objective C/RestKit experience can suggest: What's the best way to deal with this? Where does one find the 0.10 code since the plug seems to have been pulled on 0.10.x in the Git repository forcing everyone over to 0.20.0 ?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I removed RKObjectLoader.h from the framework and it built ok. Hopefully things hang together. Perhaps someone checked it in erroneously.